# Excel/VB: Filtering mulitple pivot tables using the one list of values

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, pivot-table

I am trying to filter multiple pivot tables on the one sheet from a referencing list of values but it looks like it's only processing the first With statement (CampaignAnalysis) then it returns an error (MailCount). Any help with this would be awesome! thanks!

```
Sub Test()
 Dim PI As PivotItem
 With Worksheets("In Focus - Campaign Analysis").PivotTables("CampaignAnalysis").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
 .ClearAllFilters
 For Each PI In .PivotItems
 PI.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("CA_Range1"), PI.Name) > 0
 Next PI
 End With

 Dim MC As PivotItem
 With Worksheets("In Focus - Campaign Analysis").PivotTables("MailCount").PivotFields("MailCount_CC")
 .ClearAllFilters
 For Each MC In .PivotItems
 MC.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("CA_Range1"), MC.Name) > 0
 Next MC
 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure at least one MC is visible using this filter. What may be happening is when your code tries to hide the last item in a list it will encounter an error. Without running the code myself, this is my best guess.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Brandon. I managed to get it working so I appreciate the insight. The current issue I am having at the moment is trying to update two fields in the one pivot table. The two fields are a range (which works) but the second field is a date which references back to another calculated cell

Comment: So in here, there is another PivotFields in "Segment" called "ReportDate" that I am trying to reference a calculated date cell on this sheet e.g. A1 but can't get the code working. How would I integrate a second PivotField into the code?

Comment: The whole code is below & where (****) I would like to put in the new code which is "ReportDate" PivotField being the 2nd filter in "Segment" Pivot table

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim PI As PivotItem
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CampaignAnalysis").PivotFields("Campaign  Code")
.ClearAllFilters
    For Each PI In .PivotItems
        PI.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("CA_Range1"), PI.Name) > 0
    Next PI

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MailCount").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
.ClearAllFilters
    For Each MC In .PivotItems
        MC.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("CA_Range1"), MC.Name) > 0
    Next MC

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AgeRange").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
.ClearAllFilters
    For Each AR In .PivotItems
        AR.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("CA_Range1"), AR.Name) > 0
    Next AR

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DrivablePort").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
.ClearAllFilters
    For Each DP In .PivotItems
        DP.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("CA_Range1"), DP.Name) > 0
    Next DP

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CruiseName").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
.ClearAllFilters
    For Each CN In .PivotItems
        CN.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("CA_Range1"), CN.Name) > 0
    Next CN

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CampaignName").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
.ClearAllFilters
    For Each CN2 In .PivotItems
        CN2.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("CA_Range1"), CN2.Name) > 0
    Next CN2

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Itinerary").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
.ClearAllFilters
    For Each IT In .PivotItems
        IT.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("CA_Range1"), IT.Name) > 0
    Next IT

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Segment").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
.ClearAllFilters
    For Each SG In .PivotItems
        SG.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("CA_Range1"), SG.Name) > 0
    Next SG

**-- so I would like the ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Segment").PivotFields("ReportDate") to equal a referencing calculated date cell on the same sheet e.g. cell Z4 = 12/02/2017**

End With
End With
End With
End With
End With
End With
End With
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The code above also is taking a long time to run all the pivot tables. Would you know how to filter multiple pivot tables more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lets refactor your code like this. Doing so should make it easier to debug.

```
Sub Test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim pi as PivotItem
Dim pt as PivotTable
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet ' It is best not to use activesheet and to instead
                     ' go through "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("") or something similar.


' This loop will allow us to prevent pivot tables from updating automatically
' Doing this should speed up your code dramatically.
For each pt in ws.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = True
Next


With ws.PivotTables("CampaignAnalysis").PivotFields("Campaign  Code")
    .ClearAllFilters
    ' This loop right here is going to cause an issue. If there is ever an instance
    ' where all pivotitems would be hidden by this loop, then you will encounter an error.
    ' It is best to set at least one item visible, and then loop through the items to set
    ' the other items to hidden.

    For Each pi In .PivotItems
        .Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("CA_Range1"), pi.Name) > 0
    Next
End With

With ws.PivotTables("MailCount").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
    .ClearAllFilters
    For Each pi In .PivotItems
        pi.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("CA_Range1"), pi.Name) > 0
    Next
End With

With ws.PivotTables("AgeRange").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
    .ClearAllFilters

    For Each pi In .PivotItems
        pi.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("CA_Range1"), pi.Name) > 0
    Next
End With

With ws.PivotTables("DrivablePort").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
    .ClearAllFilters

    For Each pi In .PivotItems
        pt.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("CA_Range1"), pi.Name) > 0
    Next
End With

With ws.PivotTables("CruiseName").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
    .ClearAllFilters

    For Each pi In .PivotItems
        pi.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("CA_Range1"), pi.Name) > 0
    Next
End With

With ws.PivotTables("CampaignName").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
    .ClearAllFilters

    For Each pi In .PivotItems
        pi.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("CA_Range1"), pi.Name) > 0
    Next
End With

With ws.PivotTables("Itinerary").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
    .ClearAllFilters

    For Each pi In .PivotItems
        pi.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("CA_Range1"), pi.Name) > 0
    Next pi
End With

With ws.PivotTables("Segment").PivotFields("Campaign Code")
    .ClearAllFilters

    For Each pi In .PivotItems
        pi.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("CA_Range1"), pi.Name) > 0
    Next pi
End With

'**-- so I would like the ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Segment").PivotFields("ReportDate") to equal a referencing calculated date cell on the same sheet e.g. cell Z4 = 12/02/2017**

For each pt in ws.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = False
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

As noted in comments within your code, the method you are using to hide PivotItems will encounter issues. When filtering pivotfields you will receive an error when trying to hide the last pivotitem. For example, if you have 5 items visible, and 10 items total, but during the loop the first 5 are looped through and they are all set to invisble then you will encounter an error on the 5th item, regardless of whether 6-10 should be visible.

From what I can tell, you are filtering all of your PivotTables to the same items within "Campaign Code". Why not use a slicer for this task? It is much better equipped for handling this kind of process.